# Spring Batch pause and then continue

Tags: spring-batch

I'm writing a job that will read from an excel file, x number of rows and then I'd like it to pause for an hour before it continues with the next x number of rows.
How do I do this?

I have a job.xml file which contains the following. The subscriptionDiscoverer fetches the file and pass it over to the processor. The subscriptionWriter should write another file when the processor is done.

```
<job id="subscriptionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" incrementer="jobParamsIncrementer">
    <validator ref="jobParamsValidator"/>
    <step id="readFile">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="subscriptionDiscoverer" processor="subscriptionProcessor" writer="subscriptionWriter" commit-interval="1"  />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

Is there some kind of timer I could use or is it some kind of flow structure? It's a large file of about 160000 rows that should be processed.

I hope someone has a solution they would like to share.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to understand the question, you want to process a predefined number of records (x), wait a predefined amount of time (y), then process the next block of x, and repeat?

Comment: Yes!
Repeat until the end of file.

I'm not very good at this, but maybe I could add a step which pause for y minutes and then I repeat the readFile step?
How do I then keep count of last position in the file?
I just don't understand how to do this?

Comment: I have created a file discoverer, an processor that  reads from the file and a writer that writes information from the first file.
And I think I have done it wrong. Because the processor reads 2 lines from the file but the writer just writes the last line... So I think I need an actuall reader that reads one line sends it to the processor which process it and sends the line to the writer?
I still need help with the pause and resume step and I still don't understand how I will do this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking of two possible approaches for you to start with:

1. Stop the job, and restart again (after an hour) at the last position. You can start by taking a look on how to change the BatchStatus to notify your intent to stop the job. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.0.x/cases/pause.html or look at how Spring Batch Admin implements its way of communicating the PAUSE flag (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.xhtml). You may need to implement some persistence to store the position (row number) for the job to know where to start processing again. You can use a scheduler as well to restart the job.

-or-

2. Add a [ChunkListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ChunkListener.html) and implement the following in afterChunk(ChunkContext context): Check if x number of rows has been read so far, and if yes, implement your pause mechanism (e.g., a simple Thread.sleep or look for more consistent way of pausing the step). To check for the number of rows read, you may use [StepExecution.getReadCount()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#getReadCount--) from ChunkContext.getStepContext().StepExecution().

Do note that afterChunk is called outside the transaction as indicated in the javadoc:

> Callback after the chunk is executed, outside the transaction.

Comment: option 2 may lead to transaction timeouts, because beforeChunk is called within the transaction for the chunk

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPralow. You are right, as the javadoc for beforeChunk indicates that "Callback before the chunk is executed, but inside the transaction." I edited my answer replacing it instead with afterChunk